# Book recommendation on "signals and systems"

Tags: signal, books

I'm looking for book recommendation on "signals and systems"  that will cover all the topics mentioned in the following list

## Signals and Systems:

**Linear time invariant systems:**

- impulse response,
- transfer function and frequency response of
  first- and second order systems, 
  -convolution.

**Random signals and noise:**

- probability,
- random
- variables,
- probability density function,
- autocorrelation,
- power spectral density.
- Sampling theorem,

**Discrete-time systems:**

- impulse and frequency response,
- IIR and FIR filters.

Answer (score 2):

There are many books that cover these topics - one of the better ones I have read a fair amount of is [Signals, Systems and Transforms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131989235) (now in it's 4th edition). I think this covers all (or most of) of your list.

Also, for free options, Wikibooks is developing an increasingly good library on EE and related Math subjects. There is a [Signals and Systems Wkibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Signals_and_Systems) that might be worth checking out, as well as the main [EE Wikibook page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Subject%3aElectrical_engineering) which lists the other books, and the [DSP](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/DSP) and [Mathematics](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Subject%3aMathematics) pages.